# Gradle project is not creating main java folder

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Previously when using maven every time I created a new module for the project, it created the `src/main/java` & `resources` folder and test folder, now I only have a folder called `src` this is with Fradle, any solution?

Comment: please provide more context i.e how did you create the project? is it an old project you just imported? gradle commands you ran etc

Comment: Works for me. Please provide your exact steps with video/screenshots. Check also the idea.log file (Help | Show Log in ... action) after reproducing to see if there are any exceptions.